# Does either Angry Birds or Angry Birds 2 have an ending?

Tags: angry-birds, angry-birds-2

Does either Angry Birds or Angry Birds 2 have a final level, end cutscene or some other form of an "ending"?

Web searching for "angry birds ending", "cutscene" or "final level" comes up with nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, the game keeps on updating and updating with more levels. The most recent(I think) was the Bad Piggies one, with a lot of new levels. And I won't be surprised if they add a new bird... In Angry Birds 2, they added more levels(Bamboo Forest Central Pork) recently.

Comment: It's worth noting that the 'story' basically revolves around the Pigs stealing the bird's eggs, and the Birds stealing them back, ad infinitum.

Answer (score 0):

The current answer would be none. AB2 will go on forever, and AB will continue to keep people on the Mighty League.